# Oracle PLSQL function throws PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ,for returning large data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following PLSQL functions that returns following error when returning a large data.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

**MODIFIED PLSQL FUNCTION**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FRDUSER.FRD_TELECOP_DYN_REP_SELECT_OPT (p_select IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN CLOB
AS
 -- v_temp           CLOB;
  v_out            CLOB; 
  TYPE RefCurTyp   IS REF CURSOR;      
 -- len     BINARY_INTEGER;
  v_cursor         RefCurTyp; 
  c_key            VARCHAR2 (1000);
  c_value          VARCHAR2 (1000);
  separator        VARCHAR2(3);

BEGIN

    OPEN v_cursor FOR p_select;

    -- Fetch rows from result set one at a time:
    separator := '';     

    LOOP      

      FETCH v_cursor INTO c_key,c_value;        
        EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;

   --      dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_out, TRUE);
  --       dbms_lob.open(v_out, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
         v_out := v_out ||  separator || c_key || ',' || c_value;  
  --       dbms_lob.append(v_out,  v_temp);
         separator := ':';  

    END LOOP;

    -- Close cursor:
    CLOSE v_cursor;
    RETURN (v_out);
END;
/
```

I am executing the function as below,

```
            SELECT   CASE  
                WHEN OPTIONS_TYPE = 'S' THEN    OPTIONS_VALUES
                WHEN OPTIONS_TYPE = 'D'  THEN TO_CLOB(FRD_TELECOP_DYN_REP_SELECT_OPT (OPTIONS_VALUES))  
                END  
      FROM FRD_REP_FW_REP_TEMPLATES A, FRD_REP_FW_TEMPLATES B
        WHERE A.REP_ID=1123 AND  A.TEMP_ID=B.TEMP_ID  
        ORDER BY A.REP_TEMP_ID ASC
```

When i ran the above sql query it throw following error
**ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CLOB**

The parameter to the sql function(options_values) contains sql query.

Comment: OK.  Can you post the full error stack including the line number that is throwing the error?  Can you indicate which line of your code is throwing the error?  And can you let us know what version of Oracle you're using?

Comment: @Justin : The sql query returns this ( error ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 34743, maximum: 4000) ) for the modified PLSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're overcomplicating your logic a bit.  You probably just need something like this (assuming that you actually need to dynamically pass the query in to the function)

```
SQL> create table clob_test (
  2    key varchar2(100),
  3    val varchar2(100)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into clob_test
  2    select level, dbms_random.string( 'A', 100 )
  3      from dual
  4   connect by level <= 10000;

10000 rows created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace function return_clob
  2    return clob
  3  as
  4    v_out clob;
  5    v_sql varchar2(1000) := 'select key, val from clob_test';
  6    v_key varchar2(100);
  7    v_val varchar2(100);
  8    v_rc  sys_refcursor;
  9  begin
 10    open v_rc for v_sql;
 11    loop
 12      fetch v_rc into v_key, v_val;
 13      exit when v_rc%notfound;
 14      v_out := v_out || v_key || ', ' || v_val;
 15    end loop;
 16    return v_out;
 17* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select return_clob from dual;

RETURN_CLOB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1, tzGWFXwKLgrRTGzTGbWMYMjVniIVMmCuGYGYydcrArHPRLExoFAJsZVhhPrRKyERExqRkbLGSebqX
<< more lob data removed>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your code , it throws ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
ORA-06512: at "FRDUSER.FRD_TELECOP_DYN_REP_SELECT_OPT", line 20. i have around 431 rows to be concatenated.

Comment: @SureshS - How much data are you trying to put in `V_OUT`?  Obviously, my choice of 1000 was somewhat arbitrary.  If you're trying to put more than 1000 bytes into the variable, you'd need to use a longer length.  If you're trying to put more than 4000 bytes in the variable, you'd need to use a LOB.

Comment: I am trying to place around 90000 bytes of data in V_OUT.Do i need to use DBMS_LOB function to write to the v_out ?

Comment: @SureshS - If you need more than 4000 bytes, you'd need to use a CLOB.  You may want to use some of the `DBMS_LOB` methods to write the data to the LOB.  If you're on a recent version of Oracle, however, the string functions and operators should all be overloaded to support CLOBs.

Comment: justin:can you point some links , which has some examples on how to read LOB.

Comment: @SureshS - Do you want to read or write a LOB?  Are you trying to use a CLOB or a BLOB?

Comment: i want to write to a CLOB variable(V_OUT) and then return the data

Comment: @Suresh S - Updated my answer with the new requirements.

Comment: this code throws error (ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion) when i have more than 400 rows.

Comment: @Suresh S - I updated my example to show it working with 10,000 rows where the key is 100 characters every time.  Can you post exactly what code you're running?

Comment: thanks for spending your precious time . I think I have the problem with with c_value, which is large for some cAses  .  I will post the code tomorrow , as I am out of office.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm#i1017437):

Decode:

> If expr and search are character data, then Oracle compares them using
>   nonpadded comparison semantics. expr, search, and **result can be any of
>   the datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2**. The string returned
>   is of VARCHAR2 datatype and is in the same character set as the first
>   result parameter.

So you're trying to force result of decode to be a clob, which it won't be.

Have you tried a [case statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm) instead of decode? (I haven't but worth a shot ;)

Comment: i tried to use the case statement , but it throws  ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CLOB